# Node.js DELETE Request return wrong response

Tags: node.js, postman

I'm making a DELETE request on my nodejs server, but the response is wrong.

When i try to send a DELETE request at my localhost server, it returns 
success: 0, message: "Record Not Found"
but when i go to check in the database, the parameters are gone

**index.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const userRouter = require("./api/users/user.router");
var cors = require('cors');

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/", userRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server up and running on PORT :", port);
});
```

**user.router.js**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const {
  deleteUtenti
} = require("./user.controller");
router.delete("/", deleteUtenti);

module.exports = router;
```

**user.controller.js**

```
const {
  deleteUtenti
} = require("./user.service");


module.exports = {
  deleteUtenti: (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    deleteUtenti(data, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      if (!results) {
        return res.json({
          success: 0,
          message: "Record Not Found"
        });
      }
      return res.json({
        success: 1,
        message: "user deleted successfully"
      });
    });
  }
};
```

**user.service.js**

```
const pool = require("../../config/database");

module.exports = {
  deleteUtenti: (data, callBack) => {
    pool.query(
      `delete from utenti where email = ?`,
      [data.email],
      (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
          callBack(error);
        }
        return callBack(null, results[0]);
      }
    );
  }
};
```

is it a problem of the code or of the server?

A few days ago the same thing happened to me with another function but to solve it was enough to recreate the table in the database, I tried to do the same thing but it didn't work

Comment: Are there supposed to be any results when you're deleting a record?

Comment: What is your DB engine? and which node package is used to access it?

Comment: My db engine is mysql, i use the mysql package, the delete request work, the only problem is the response. It gives me success: 0 instead of success: 1

Answer (score 0):

I Just found the problem, `results[0]` on **user.service.js** did not read the response from the database, so to do some tests I changed it to `results` where all the response from the database came out and I saw that I just had to take the affectedRows response from the database, so I changed it to `results.affectedRows` and now everything works as it should.